# User table having totalExpense column no getting updated

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a controller which is taking input expense details and updating it in user table ,but the totalExpense column is not getting updated

```js
postAddExpense = async (req, res, next) => {
    //post always uses body
    try {
        const money = req.body.money;
        const description = req.body.description;
        const options = req.body.options;
        console.log('money = ' + money);
        console.log('description = ' + description);
        console.log('options = ' + options);
        console.log('userid = ' + req.user.id);
        if (money == '' || money == undefined || description == '' || description == undefined || options == '' || options == undefined) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Input fields are empty' })
        }

        const expenseData = await Expense.create({
            money: money,
            description: description,
            options: options,
            userid: req.user.id
        });
        //to keep the total money updated spend by the user every time new expense is added 
        const totalExpense = Number(req.user.totalExpense) + Number(money);
        console.log('totalExpense = ' + totalExpense);
        //this returns promise
        const [updatedRowsCount, updatedRows] = await User.update({
            totalExpenses: totalExpense
        },
            {
                where: {
                    id: req.user.id
                },
                
            });

        console.log('Updated rows count:', updatedRowsCount);
        console.log('Updated rows:', updatedRows);  

        res.status(200).json({ newExpenseData: expenseData, message: 'Data added successfully' })
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('post expense err = ' + err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err })
    }
}
```

want to get the total expense money by user id wise

Answer (score 0):

You are updating a column named totalExpenses, but in your code, you are using totalExpense and ensure that the Sequelize model for the User table has the correct field name (totalExpenses), try this code:-

```
const totalExpenses = Number(req.user.totalExpenses) + Number(money);
console.log('totalExpenses = ' + totalExpenses);

const [updatedRowsCount, updatedRows] = await User.update({
    totalExpenses: totalExpenses // <-- Corrected column name
},
{
    where: {
        id: req.user.id
    },
});
```

Comment: The `const totalExpense` local variable and `User.update({ totalExpenses: totalExpense }, { .... })` is fine, there is no issue here. Perhaps you meant to say that the `User.update` property should be `totalExpense` to match the column OP says isn't getting updated.